# Por favor, me podrían ayudar con el siguiente error de ReportViewer?

Tags: reportviewer, aspx

estoy trabajando en Visual 19, con una aplicación web que tienen reportviewer 10.0 y instale los nugets de la versión correspondiente a mi proyecto pero nada que resuelvo error, es decir no puedo manipular el diseñador del Report, ya hice varias acciones que me encontrado en internet pero ninguna hasta ahora a funcionado,por lo tanto a la hora de ejecutar mi reporte no tiene buena vista la barra de ReportViewer[image: error en VS]

[image: así se ve en funcionamiento]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y subir la imagen no es suficiente para poder ayudarte. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ReportViewer en su version 10 no creo que este en Nuget, ya que es [ReportViewer 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=6442) y necesitas el runtime (y quizá los CLR) instalado(s) para que funcione correctamente.

Saludos